# i am i getting notice: undefined pss

Tags: php

here is my php. the session ps comes from a another php page. it comes successfully. but i am getting undefined when i try to use it on the following code to connect to my db.

```
    <?php
$pss = "";
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ps'])){
    $pss = $_SESSION['ps'];
}

echo $pss;
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","erthiph_asksheikh851821217");

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`, `Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
('','','','".$pss."','','',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
?>
```

the  above code works. i replaced '$_POST[postquestion]' with '".@pss."'
please check edit history to check edits.

Comment: pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: `$_POST[pss]` needs to change to `$pss`? isn't it?

Comment: edited. now it gives undefined index (value from session)

Comment: i know its same as the duplicate flagged post but i read the post and could not get whats wrong

Comment: no its not pretty obvious :) thats why i am asking

Comment: @Fred-ii- : i hope you have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `'$_POST[$pss]'` to `'".$pss."'`

Comment: that must be a comment? don't you think?

Comment: now it gives undefined index

Comment: @A-2-A I can comment only my post. Im under 50 rep.  sorry

Comment: i dont get why they rush to flag as duplicate. i came here because i didnt get it. no one is full of sql knowledge. they dont even bother reading the comments.

Comment: anyway thanks for your reply A-2-A

Comment: Ok. After change. it doesnt work ?

Comment: hmm. you should change only in INSERT - ... `void', '$_POST[$pss]', 'null'`... to ...`void', '".$pss."', 'null'`...

Comment: @Olbrych after change to $pss it gives undefined index: (and here goes the value passed onto session.)

Comment: @Olbrych that solves the error yes. now im worried about the sql query not going through to database.

Comment: @Erthiph Can you add to your post current code ? I'm confused now. You want insert `$pss` or some POST from `$_POST[$pss]`

Comment: @Olbrych thanks for your help :) i fixed the sql lines too and it works now

Comment: @Olbryc check my edit. thanks. it works now.